# Python Spacy similarity without loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, similarity, spacy

I am trying to allow users to enter a search term to find top 5 articles matching their search. I am in the process of comparing the results / performance for a variety of methods (gensim word2vec, doc2vec, nearest neighbour etc).

I have successfully created code to leverage standard similarity function in Spacy, however, as it loops through a massive list of documents appending the similarity score to a pandas df, it takes too long.

Is there a method to return the top 5 most similar documents without the loop and pandas append? The reason is that this method returns the most sensible top 5 documents compared to the others (the joy of the word embeddings!)

```
#load relevant libraries
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import spacy
#load spacy model
nlp=spacy.load('Z:\\en_core_web_lg-2.0.0')
#
#Get Doc Corpus
dfCorpus = pd.read_csv('z:\DocumentCorpus.csv', delimiter=',')
##get top 5 using spacy similarity function 
SearchStringCosine = nlp(input('Enter search term:'))
computed_similarities = []
for i in dfCorpus.CorpusInput_Unqiue:
   doc=nlp(i)
   computed_similarities.append((i, SearchStringCosine.similarity(doc)))
computed_similarities = sorted(computed_similarities, key=lambda item: -item[1])
computed_similarities = pd.DataFrame(computed_similarities,columns=   ['CorpusInput_Unique','Score'])
print(computed_similarities[:5])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else looking for a solution to this, I found the best method was to pickle my file post applying spacy vector nlp(), then the loop works almost instantaneously when referencing doc_list!

```
dfCorpusDescr = dfCorpus.fieldname
doc_list={i: nlp(i) for i in dfCorpus}
with open("filename.pickle", 'wb') as pfile:
    pickle.dump(doc_list, pfile, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

Answer (score 4):

Cosine similarity (the `.similarity` function in Spacy) is a simple linear algebraic operation which can be efficiently parallelized. You want to compute `cos(x,y) = x⋅y / (|x||y|)`, where `⋅` is the inner product operator.

Instead of looping over different `x`s for a given `y`, what you could instead do is have `x` be a matrix and perform a simple vector-matrix product. Let `x` be your matrix of document vectors (of dimensionality Nx300 - N the number of documents, 300 the number of features) and `y` be your comparison vector:

```
vector_norms = np.array([np.sqrt(np.sum(np.square(v))) for v in X])
X = (X.T / vector_norms).T
similarities = np.matmul(X, y) 
# ... perform index sorting as usual
```

This can be written on a GPU-accelarated linear algebra library if more efficiency is required.

Comment: WOW, thanks for the excellent prompt response! Ill give that a go and let you know how I get on.  thanks once again.

Comment: I never managed to get this to work. Tried so many variations but could never get the similarities call to work despite normalising my corpus and search terms.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: in the latest version of the code I can locate (serial delete of what doesn't work!) im getting error "'list' object has no attribute 'T'". The document corpus (X) is a list with word vectors.                                        vector_norms = np.array([np.sqrt(np.sum(np.square(v))) for v in dfCorpusWV])
X = (dfCorpusWV.T / vector_norms).T

Comment: `X = (X.T / vector_norms).T` what is T in the above? A property of X? Yet it is also used as a separate multiplier?